# how to set the DOCKER_HOST?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was doing the django-shop tutorial from this link:https://django-shop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/quickstart.html . I  am very new in docker ,docker-compose and linux .

I get this error:

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http://127.0.0.1:2375 - is
>   it running?
>
> If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the
>   DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

When I execute these commands...

```
$ git clone --depth 1 github.com/awesto/django-shop 
$ cd django-shop 
$ export DJANGO_SHOP_TUTORIAL=commodity 
$ docker-compose up --build -d
```

I tried to do this Tutorial and this didn't work.

*EDIT*:
I use this Command to solve this problem:

$ sudo adduser razvan docker

Comment: What steps did you take to encounter this issue? Do you know for certain that the Docker daemon is at a different IP/port?

Comment: $ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/awesto/django-shop
$ cd django-shop
$ export DJANGO_SHOP_TUTORIAL=commodity
$ docker-compose up --build -d

Comment: I used these steps

Comment: Thank, Razvan! I submitted an edit to add them to your question. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Docker to help. But hopefully the extra context will help someone else provide an answer.

Answer (score 10):

As a general rule, never set `DOCKER_HOST`.

Given your error message, it looks like it might be set (incorrectly) and you might see if things get better if you

```sh
unset DOCKER_HOST
```

The two prominent exceptions are VM-based Docker environments (Docker Toolbox, Docker Machine, Kubernetes' minikube).  In these cases there are helper scripts that can set it to the correct value:

```sh
eval $(docker-machine env)   # Docker Machine, Docker Toolbox
eval $(minikube docker-env)  # Minikube
```

Answer (score 3):

By set `DOCKER_HOST` you tell for every run of docker in command line to use **http api**, instead of default - **socket** on **localhost**.

By default **http api** is turned off

```
$ sudo cat /lib/systemd/system/docker.service | grep ExecStart
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

you can add `-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375` for tern on **http api** on **localhos**t 
but usually you want to tern on api for **remote servers** by `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` **(!!! do it only with proper firewall !!!)**

so you need to change in  `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` to next line

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 so I went at the end of the /home/user/.profile file and placed the `unset DOCKER_HOST` command. 
Then sourced the file like so: `source /home/user/.profile` then logged out and logged back in and docker now works normally.