# how to ssh to docker container created from one machine (centos) from another machine(centos or mac)

Tags: docker, networking

I want to create a docker container from one machine (suppose having centos) machine and then access that container from another machine(may be centos or mac). How can we do that?  Is it possible with macvlan networking? If yes , what are steps? If not, what is the way?

Comment: Does the `docker run -p` option help you at all?  How are you building and launching the container now?  Why "ssh" in particular?

Comment: we install app on baremetal machine and then do ssh to baremetal on our corp network. So now instead of baremetal we are trying to install app/run to docker container instead of baremetal and do ssh on to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends from what is your final goal. Following are some approaches (depending on what you want to achieve as final goal):

1. Manage container and execute `bash` in the container on a remote host:

   Easiest way is to use the environment variable DOCKER_HOST

   ```
   export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://vagrant@192.168.5.178
   docker exec -ti centos_remote /bin/bash
   ```

   You can find more information in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51897942/2816703
2. Use the container as a form of virtual machine on which user can ssh:

   First you will need a container that is running the `sshd`. You will expose the port 22 on another port on the host network. Finally you will use the `ssh` with `-p` to connect that port. Here is a working example:

   ```
   $ sudo docker run -d -P --name test_sshd rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:14.04
   $ sudo docker port test_sshd 22
     0.0.0.0:49154

   $ ssh root@localhost -p 49154
   # The password is `root`
   root@test_sshd $
   ```

   or if you are on a remote machine, use the host IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, to connect to the container use:

   ```
   $ ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 49154
   # The password is `root`
   ```

   Also you can pre-select a port (in this case port 22000) and test from the host.

   ```
   ~# docker run -d -p 22000:22 --name test_sshd rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:14.04   
   ~# ssh root@<ipaddress> -p 22000
   ```
3. Setup a network layer (L2/L3) between the hosts:

   Using macvlan is one approach. Another approach is the ipvlan. In both cases, you are converting the host network adapter to a virtual router, after which you need to setup the routes. You can find detailed explanation on this link http://networkstatic.net/configuring-macvlan-ipvlan-linux-networking/

Comment: I guess with point, you are trying to run container image on one machine and trying to ssh  to that image from same machine. i dont need this.   I need to ssh from another machine not from that machine. Did you migunderstood my question?  is point3 is also doing same thing?

Comment: Same applies, if you expose the container's port 22, you can ssh to it from wherever you want. Just replace "localhost" with the ip of the host

Comment: i followed below steps
1)docker run -d -P --name test_sshd rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:14.04
90f0c64ac74b601a86ec0b6043368845f55fce8262a2e44225e2b20b8014fb2a

2)docker port test_sshd 22
0.0.0.0:32769

Comment: 3)docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
90f0c64ac74b        rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:14.04   "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:32769->22/tcp   test_sshd

4)AUX756844:~ YogeshYadav$ ssh root@10.195.1.131 -p 32769
ssh: connect to host 10.195.1.131 port 49154: Connection refused

Comment: Your port is "32769" that is mapped to 22 (see the response from the command "0.0.0.0:32769->22"). Use this port in -p

Comment: You can use `docker run -d -p 22000:22 --name test_sshd rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:14.04` to tell docker to map 22000 to port 22 (instead of a random port). Than use `ssh root@<ipaddress> -p 22000`

Comment: ssh root@10.195.1.131 -p 32769, this worked . I was  not giving password as "root". Thanks. Do we need to use password as "root" or can we use our credentials also which we used to login to baremaetal(mean corp credetials). Also can you show Dockerfile written to create this image

Comment: Approach is same as in baremetal. If you don't want to give password, set up the local user's ssh identity and set up the  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in the container. My suggestion is to try to build your own container based on the distribution you want (ex. centos) and add the public keys of the users. You can find the good starting point on https://github.com/rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd