# Docker Desktop on Mac issue with ssh to centos container on localhost

Tags: macos, docker, ssh, localhost, desktop

I know there are similar questions on the SO but many of the suggestions have not worked for me. I'm running Docker Desktop for Mac and I startup a docker container I've built that has ssh configured and running (I use these to connect to AWS, Azure etc). I startup the container with something like (the ubc/jlbase/jlbase image has ssh configure... and the following all works on a linux machine with docker0 network in place)

```
docker run -P --name test -d ubc/jlbase/jlbase
docker inspect test |grep IP
ping -c *the_ip_from_above*
```

does not connect. From what I can find, this is a known issue with Docker on Mac... but the help and links I've found don't seem to solve the problem. Can someone tell me what I've missed?

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address is mostly an implementation detail and you shouldn't need it at all on any OS.  You should be able to access the container through its `docker run -p` published ports.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that this is a know feature of Docker on Mac, not an issue. Docker on Mac is running on a virtual machine inside macOS, so the IP address you receive is the IP of the container inside the VM, not on macOS.

To address the two issues from the question:

#### How to enable ssh

To be able to `ssh` on your container, you will need to have the `sshd` running in the container and to publish the port `22`. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311979/how-to-ssh-to-docker-container-created-from-one-machine-centos-from-another-ma/66314132#66314132) to see how you can try this with a container that is already prepared

#### How to ping

Since the docker is running inside a VM, to be able to route traffic to the containers, you will need to setup the network layer to route the traffic. One approach is to create a tunnel between the VM and the machine.

This is much more complex setup and will require a help of a CNF (Conteinerized Network Function). One of the simplest CNF that was created just for this problem is [soctun](https://github.com/SciSpike/soctun) which creates a tunnel between the host and the docker network layer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have to use a specific '-p' setting for exposing the ports... the -P doesn't seem to work (in the sense that the docker port <container_name> 22 says that no port is exposed. BTW, the root password is not 'root'.... did I miss something?

Comment: You can try `docker run -d -p 22000:22 --name test_sshd rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:14.04` and than `ssh root@localhost -p 22000`. In this container the password is `root`

Comment: For your specific image, if it's not prepared with `sshd`, you need to install, enable/configure the `sshd` and export the port `22` and then you will be able to use it in the same way.

Comment: So with this procedure... will I be able to ping the container? Which command should I use? I'd like to test with ping just so I can better figure out what is going on. And again.... a straightforward startup of my docker image (it has sshd configured) on a linux  install of docker has the ping work in a rather straightforward way. What is it in these suggestions that is getting around the differences with Docker Desktop running on mac. I'm asking because I'll need to sort out these issue for a windows machine running docker as well. Thanks!

Comment: Answer updated to address the `ping` problem

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed answer. The soctun option looks interesting but complicated. I'm trying to develop an application so any user can download my app and setup some complicated containers with scientific tools configured and installed ... running on their local machine. So... I'm worried about the soctun solution making this option much harder to get to work for any general user.

Comment: The only reason that I can think of that demands network access are the CNF containers (routers, firewalls, ...).  However, if you think that you might have challenge with some aspect of your application because you don't have direct network access, place it on SO and we will try to answer it.