# Can't run docker as a normal user

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I can't run docker commands as my own user.  But I know that the service is running because I can run commands as sudo:

```
$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                 PORTS                    NAMES
(snip)         (snip)            (snip)                   13 days ago     Up 2 hours (healthy)   9000/tcp                 (snip)
```

I am successfully running a few containers, and they each work, but I have another not listed in   that I need to run as my own user.

I am part of the docker group:

```
$ groups
docker www-data video tim
```

I'm not sure what else to check.  I do have this:

```
$ echo $DOCKER_HOST
unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock
```

Also:

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-65-generic
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
```

This is on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Does the answer in this question help you? https://askubuntu.com/q/477551/117753 Until recently, these were the steps that you need to do to have use Docker without sudo: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: The post-install steps are simply adding the current user to the `docker` group.  And as mentioned in the question, I'm already a member of that group.  Running `docker-rootless.sh` yields `[rootlesskit:parent] error: failed to setup UID/GID map: newuidmap 25367 [0 1000 1 1 100000 65536] failed: newuidmap: Target process 25367 is owned by a different user: uid:1000 pw_uid:1000 st_uid:1000, gid:999 pw_gid:1000 st_gid:999`

Comment: You may need to sign out and back in to get it to work

Comment: I've rebooted since adding myself to the `docker` group

Answer (score 4):

As you followed all the post installation steps correctlly, as far as I can tell, my best guess is that has to do with the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable.

Does it help if you unset `DOCKER_HOST`? (Perhaps you need to log out, so it has an effect.)

On my system, `docker ps` works with `sudo`, but once I set `DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock`, I get the same error as you.

For some background, here is a [question about the DOCKER_HOST variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51878186/783510). In essence, that variable should normally not be set.

Comment: To add to this. I was setting the variable as a remnant of non-root config in my .zshrc/bashrc file.

Answer (score 2):

Return to the default sock path (unix:///var/run/docker.sock), by unsetting DOCKER_HOST and removing an errant config files:

`unset DOCKER_HOST`
`rm -r ~/.docker`

The Docker Daemon must be restarted after creating the “docker” group:
`sudo services docker restart`

Then, ensure you add your current user to the group:
`sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER`

This will ensure your user has access to the socket file.

UPDATE: 12/2022
Recently had to do this on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and ran into the *login shell* persisting the previous group.

Since the UI manages the *login shell*, a restart is either required, or you need to replace the process with `exec`. You can work around this issue, until you restart, by replacing your current shell process: (use $0 instead, if $SHELL doesn't match your preferred shell)

```
exec sudo -u $USER -E $SHELL
```

Comment:  Even after restarting the daemon, the error persists.  And `$SUDO_USER` isn't a variable

Comment: `SUDO_USER` _is_ a variable... after you've used `sudo` to change users in the current session. However, because shell expansions take place _before_ `sudo` runs, @git_driver probably meant to just suggest `$USER` there.

Comment: `sudo echo $SUDO_USER` outputs an empty string

Comment: I doubt this particular case matters much if `SUDO_USER` exists (you won't need it for the normal user run condition of your question), but shells will expand `$foo` in `sudo echo $foo` before `sudo` executes

Comment: Whichever variable is being used, does it really matter since my user is already part of the group AS MENTIONED IN THE QUESTION?